# Posting file objects: illegal invocation

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I'd like to post multiple images objects to testphp.php. but the console prints errors says illegal invocation.

I have tried:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="/script/googleapis.js"></script>


<input multiple type="file" id="myFile" size="50">

<div id="sub">submit</div>

<div id="testtest"></div>

<script>
$("#sub").click(function(){
    // get the file objects
    var files = $("#myFile")[0].files;
    for (var i = 0; i < files.length; i++){
    //test if the files[i] has the file objects
    console.log(files[i]);
    //post objects to another php file
    $.post("testphp.php", {img: files[i]}, function(result){
                                $("#testtest").html(result);
                            });
    }


})
```

Answer (score 1):

You can't do that.  If you want to post files, you'll need to use `FormData`.

I'd also suggest uploading all the files at once, instead of posting one at a time.

To post `FormData`, you'll need to use `$.ajax` instead.

```
$("#sub").click(function(){
    // get the file objects
    var files = $("#myFile")[0].files,
        data = new FormData;

    for (var i = 0; i < files.length; i++){
        //test if the files[i] has the file objects
        console.log(files[i]);
        //post objects to another php file
        data.append('img[]', files[i]);
    }

    $.ajax({
        url: "testphp.php",
        type: "POST",
        data: data,
        contentType: false,
        processData: false,
        success: function(result){
            $("#testtest").html(result);
        }
    });
});
```

Now in PHP, your `$_FILES['img']['name']` (and the other keys) may be arrays, if you are uploading multiple files.

Comment: Thanks a lot, it works perfect. Would you like to share more about what's special about the new FormData? I'm kindda new to javascript.

Comment: `FormData` is a new thing (it's part of XHR2).  More info here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FormData/Using_FormData_Objects